# How to build a webpack library that is attached to window["MyCompany"] namespace

Tags: webpack, module

I'm trying to build a UMD module with Webpack.  The module will be compiled into modern frameworks, but we also want it to work well in existing products where it may be loaded by RequireJS or even injected via a `<script>` tag.  For the latter, I want to attach it to an existing object on the window and not overwrite that object.   For example:
`window.MyCompany.MyModuleA`

Other modules may be built using this technique if I can get it to work. So, we could have the following scenario:

```
window.MyCompany.MyModuleA
window.MyCompany.MyModuleB
```

If `window.MyCompany.MyModuleB` is lazy-loaded, I don't want it to override containing object `window.MyCompany` or any previously attached child objects/modules.

I've been able to configure my webpack config to export, window.MyCompanyMyModuleA, but I can't get the module defined on an object that already exists on the window without overwriting it.  This is my latest config:

```
output: {
  library: "MyModuleA",
  libraryTarget: "umd",
  libraryExport: "MyCompany"
  ...
}
```

I've also tried a variety of configurations noted here with no success.
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibraryexport

My fallback plan is to just define the target so it attaches to the window as `window.MyCompanyMyModuleA` and then have a self invoking function setup the convenience, company-scoped object, `window.MyCompany`, but I'm hoping that I can make this a bit cleaner and deal with it at build time.

Also tried the following and `window.MyCompany` is defined, but `window.MyCompany.MyModuleA` is undefined.
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/multi-part-library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it!

Changed to using named entry points and then an array to create the namespace object and attach the module, like so:

```
entry: {
   MyModuleA: "./src/my-module-a.ts"
},
```

and

```
output: {
  library: ["MyCompany", "[name]"],
  libraryTarget: "umd",
  filename: "my-module-a.js",
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/umd/"),
},
```